# How to call SharePoint list form, from other SharePoint list form, on clicking Next button?

Tags: sharepoint

I have two lists, List A and List B, now I need to call "List B form" from "List A form" on clicking "next button of List A form". Its like series of different forms of lists, i need to call one after other. These list are under same site. So it will be like a wizard that will run on different lists.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the new form for List A to add the next button to show the new form of List B.You can modify the NewForm.aspx through SharePoint Designer by following similar steps in the article below,

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-form-HA010119111.aspx

You can even display the new forms inside a modal dialog using SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog to give a wizard feel.

Comment: creating new button is not an issue, what i need is to iterate on different lists, i have some infopath forms, that are associated with their respective lists, and i need to make a wizard using these info path (SPlist) forms.

Comment: I am exploring your suggestion regarding SP.UI.ModelDialog.